Jasmine test Observable
I have a service class in an Angular application that I need to write tests for. The service class works well, but I am unable to write the Jasmine unit test.
The service class subscribes to an observable in a websocket class with a class method, and upon execution of this local method, calls the next on a class observable with the result and return that observable. This next never gets called.
To illustrate
class MyServiceClass {
   constructor() {
     this.websocketSubject.subscribe(this.funProcessing);
   }
   results = new Subject<MyType>();
   signalEnd = new Subject<void>();
   private _funProcessing(responseFromSocket) {
     if (resonseFromSocket == likeTheResponse) {
       results.next(responseFromSocket);
     
   getResponse(query) {
     this.websocketSubject.send(query);
     return this.results;
   }
}

Some things that I've tried with tests
it('should process a message ', (done) => {
    /* service = createSpyFromClass(MyServiceClass, {
      observablePropsToSpyOn: ['results'],
    }); */
    service = TestBed.inject(MyServiceClass);
    const envv = jasmine.getEnv();
    envv.allowRespy(true);

    let actual: Response | undefined;
    service.results.subscribe((value) => {
      actual = value;
      done();
    });
    spyOn(service, 'getResponse').withArgs(1).and.callThrough();
    //service.getResponse(1);
    expect(actual?.index).toEqual(1);

  });

This service works well, it's only the test that don't work. If I log to console from tests, I can see that the funProcessing gets called, but results.next never triggers.
I've tried many things, spies, callbacks done/done(), fakeasync, jasmine-auto-spies, absolutely nothing works.

please check the code for MyServiceClass it does not make sense, where is likeTheResponse coming from?

'likeTheResponse' comes from socket, the method is subscribed as callback in the constructor,
I'll rename maybe that is confusing

I think expect blocks should be placed before done is executed.
it('should process a message ', (done) => {
    /* service = createSpyFromClass(MyServiceClass, {
      observablePropsToSpyOn: ['results'],
    }); */
    service = TestBed.inject(MyServiceClass);
    const envv = jasmine.getEnv();
    envv.allowRespy(true);

    let actual: Response | undefined;
    service.results.subscribe((value) => {
      actual = value;
      expect(actual?.index).toEqual(1);
      done();
    });
    spyOn(service, 'getResponse').withArgs(1).and.callThrough();
    service.getResponse(1);

});


Test still fails., although un-commenting the last line service.getResponse(1) caused the subscription block to be executed, but the value passed into it is undefined, so may be a different error

Aah sorry, In trying to get the test to work, somewhere along I set the wrong message in the mocked websocket, resulting in undefined message,
The test did work,
Executing the service and having the spy on it worked
Thanks,
